# Expo App on Android device some onPress() not firing

Tags: react-native, expo, jsx

Several issues are happening here:

1. Only the delete icon fires onPress()
2. I've tried different nesting of JSX components to get the update icon to fire with no luck
3. If it matters, for some reason the 'back' arrow in the StackNavigator on this same page doesn't work either.
4. This code works perfectly on AVD and IOS simulator
5. The alpha effect of the TouchableOpacity component isn't being rendered

I've googled extensively, and the only similar problem has to with absolute positioning the TouchableOpacity component, which isn't my case.

I've also tried to onPress = {() Alert('click')} and nothing happened on the Android device.

````
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.detailsPanel}>
        {/* first row */}

        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.firstColumn}>
            <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.blue} weight='bold'>
              {route.params.item.date}
            </AppText>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.secondColumn}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.blue} weight='bold'>
                {route.params.item.aircraft_type}
              </AppText>
              <AppText>{"  "}</AppText>
              <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.blue} weight='bold'>
                {route.params.item.registration}
              </AppText>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.thirdColumn}>
            <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.blue} weight='bold'>
              {route.params.item.duration}
            </AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
        {/* second row */}
        <Separator />
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.firstColumn}>
            <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
              {route.params.item.route}
            </AppText>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.thirdColumn}>
            <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
              {route.params.item.pilot_in_command ? "PIC" : ""}
              {route.params.item.second_in_command ? "SIC" : ""}
              {route.params.item.solo ? "Solo" : ""}
              {route.params.item.dual ? "Dual" : ""}
            </AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
        {/* third row */}
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.firstColumn}>
            <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
              <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
                Landings:
              </AppText>
              {route.params.item.landings_day ? (
                <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
                  {" "}
                  Day {route.params.item.landings_day}
                </AppText>
              ) : null}
              {route.params.item.landings_night ? (
                <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
                  {" "}
                  Night {route.params.item.landings_night}
                </AppText>
              ) : null}
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.secondColumn}></View>
          <View style={styles.thirdColumn}>
            <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
              {route.params.item.instructor ? "  CFI" : ""}
            </AppText>
          </View>
        </View>

        {/* fourth row */}
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.firstColumn}>
            <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
              {route.params.item.night ? (
                <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
                  Night {route.params.item.night}
                  {"  "}
                </AppText>
              ) : null}
              {route.params.item.instrument ? (
                <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
                  Inst {route.params.item.instrument}
                  {"  "}
                </AppText>
              ) : null}
              {route.params.item.simulated_instrument ? (
                <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
                  Hood {route.params.item.simulated_instrument}
                  {"  "}
                </AppText>
              ) : null}
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.thirdColumn}>
            <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black}>
              {route.params.item.cross_country ? "XC" : ""}
              {route.params.item.simulator ? "  Sim" : ""}
            </AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.firstColumn}>
            <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
              {approaches.map((appr, index) => (
                <AppText size={16} color={STYLES.black} key={index}>
                  {appr.approach_type}-{appr.number}{" "}
                </AppText>
              ))}
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.thirdColumn}>
            {route.params.item.hold ? <AppText size={16}>Hold</AppText> : null}
          </View>
        </View>

        {/* fifth row */}
        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View style={styles.firstColumn}>
            <AppText>{route.params.item.remarks}</AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
        {/* sixth row */}
        <Separator />
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 5 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 2,
              backgroundColor: STYLES.danger,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              showAlert(
                route.params.item.id,
                route.params.item.date,
                route.params.item.route
              );
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name={"delete"}
                size={30}
                color={STYLES.white}
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("FlightUpdate", {
                item: route.params.item,
              });
            }}
            style={{
              flex: 2,
              backgroundColor: STYLES.blue,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name={"update"}
                size={30}
                color={STYLES.white}
                style={{ padding: 5 }}
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        mapPadding={{
          top: 60,
          bottom: 10,
          right: 40,
          left: 40,
        }}
        ref={mapRef}
      >
        {markers.map((marker) => (
          <Marker
            key={marker.key}
            coordinate={marker.coordinates}
            title={marker.title}
          />
        ))}
        <Polyline
          strokeColor={STYLES.blue}
          strokeWidth={3}
          geodesic={true}
          coordinates={polylines}
        />
      </MapView>
      <ActivityModal visible={Context.activityVisibleValue}></ActivityModal>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  detailsPanel: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: "100%",
    margin: 0,
    backgroundColor: STYLES.white,
    borderRadius: STYLES.borderRadius,
    padding: STYLES.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: STYLES.white,
    borderRadius: STYLES.borderRadius,
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    paddingBottom: 5,
  },
  firstColumn: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  secondColumn: {
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  thirdColumn: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
  },

  text: {
    fontFamily: STYLES.font,
    color: STYLES.blue,
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    borderRadius: STYLES.borderRadius,
  },
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Expo and React Navigation, I expected that `react-native-gesture-handler` package is already installed.

Try to import any touchable component ( TouchableOpacity or TouchableHighlight) from `react-native-gesture-handler` in place of `react-native`

```
import {TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight} from "react-native-gesture-handler"
```

Make sure that your code is not wrapped inside any modal component or Bottom Sheet.

Some of those modals wrapped child components inside another touchable component which blocks touch events to propagate to nested children components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the late response. I narrowed it down to the MapView component interfering with the onPress events in the other components. Everything works great when MapView is commented out.
What do you mean by BottomSheet?

I'm still working on a resolution.

Comment: Bottom Sheet are component reveal from bottom - https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet .

Can reproduce a minified version of the issue on Expo Snack.
https://snack.expo.dev/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I would recommend importing {ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from react-native, not react-native-gesture-handler; Worked for me; Expo Version 45